# How to integrate SSRS matrix report into PowerBI

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I've got SSRS matrix report created and need to integrate that to PowerBI and then publish it. Please suggest as am new to this integrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS report can be integrated to PowerBI using Pin mechanism, check this article
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4136/pinning-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-to-power-bi/

The following report items can be pinned to a Power BI dashboard. You cannot pin items that are nested inside a data region. For example you cannot pin an item that is nested inside a Reporting Services table or list.

1.Charts

2.Gauge panels

3.Maps

4.Images

Items need to be in the report body. You cannot pin items that are in the page header or page footer.
You can pin individual items that are inside a top level rectangle but you cannot pin them all as a single group.

> Since your report is of matrix type, which inturn is tabular - its not
>   possible to pin/integrate your matrix report to PowerBI.

This feature is not available yet, check this article for more info.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pin-reporting-services-items-to-power-bi-dashboards?view=sql-server-2017